Blazor Server JS interop DotNetObjectReference keeps state longer then wanted
I have several Blobs in a DB. These are displayed in an IFrame on a Popup, after the user clicks the button for a file on one of several possible components (.razor files). This works fine as long as I stay on the first component where I opened the Popup, but if I leave the component and reenter it i will always have null or empty on the IFrameSrc. This will also happen if I go to another component that could open a PDF. Reloading the page or opening it in a new Tab always fixes the problem. I noticed that when I dispose of the DotNetObjectReference at the end of HandelWantedFile further opening of PDFs will always throw an Excpetion and it will display the first file I opend on that component. This could be due to me not revoking the URL, but I still do not get how the old IFrameSrc is served instead.
Exception:

blazor.server.js:1   Uncaught (in promise) Error:
System.ArgumentException: There is no tracked object with id '5'.
Perhaps the DotNetObjectReference instance was already disposed.
(Parameter 'dotNetObjectId')    at Microsoft.JSInterop.…64
dotNetObjectId)    at
Microsoft.JSInterop.Infrastructure.DotNetDispatcher.BeginInvokeDotNet(JSRuntime
jsRuntime,…fo, String argsJson)
at y.endInvokeDotNetFromJS (blazor.server.js:1:3502)
at Xt._invokeClientMethod (blazor.server.js:1:61001)
at Xt._processIncomingData (blazor.server.js:1:58476)
at Xt.connection.onreceive (blazor.server.js:1:52117)
at s.onmessage (blazor.server.js:1:80262)

Does anybody have a idead on how to fix this or is able to point me in the right direction? I am currently unable to fix this myself. I need to display files from several components without forcing a reload upon first entering a component that could call the popup.
@* PdfPopUp.razor *@
@namespace Project.Pages
        
<MudDialog Style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
 <DialogContent>
  @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(IframeSrc))
  {
    <iframe id="pdfIframe" src="@IframeSrc" style="width: 100%; height: 100vh; border: none;"
      frameborder="0"></iframe>
  }
  else
  {
    <p>Error: IFrameSrc is not set.</p>
  }
 </DialogContent>
</MudDialog>
        
@code {
 [Parameter] public string IframeSrc { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

I call the PopUp like this
@* FirstComponent.razor *@
@page "/FirstComponent"
@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "user")]

@namespace Project.Pages

@inject IDialogService dialogService
@inject IJSRuntime javaScript

<button class="link-button" @onclick="@(x => HandleWantedFile()">@FileName@FileType</button>
@code {
 [Parameter] public string IFrameSrc { get; set; } = string.Empty;

 private async Task HandleWantedFile()
 {
   byte[] file;
   file = await whaterver();//db call
   var dotNetReference = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
   await javaScript.InvokeVoidAsync("initializeBlobUrlCreation", 
    dotNetReference);
   await javaScript.InvokeVoidAsync("createAndSetBlobUrl", "pdfIframe",
    file, "application/pdf", dotNetReference);
   var options = new DialogOptions { FullWidth = true, MaxWidth = 
    MaxWidth.Large, CloseButton = true};
   dialogService.Show<PdfPopUp>(currentBlob.FileName, 
    new DialogParameters { ["IFrameSrc"] = this.IFrameSrc }, options);
 }
      
 [JSInvokable]
 public async Task SetIframeSource(string url)
 {
   IFrameSrc = url;
   await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
 }
}

my JavaScript:
//wwwroot/JS/site.js
function initializeBlobUrlCreation(dotNetRef) {
    window.createAndSetBlobUrl = function(iframeId, byteArray, mimeType) {
        var blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(byteArray)], { type: mimeType });
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        dotNetRef.invokeMethodAsync('SetIframeSource', url);
        var iframeElement = document.getElementById(iframeId);
        if (iframeElement) {
            iframeElement.src = url;
        }
    };
}

function createAndSetBlobUrl(iframeId, byteArray, mimeType) {
    var blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(byteArray)], { type: mimeType });
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('Project', 'SetIframeSource', dotNetReference, url);
    var iframeElement = document.getElementById(iframeId);
    if (iframeElement) {
        iframeElement.src = url;
        scalePDF(iframeId);
    }
}

function scalePDF(iframeId) {
    var iframe = document.getElementById(iframeId);
    if (iframe) {
        iframe.onload = function () {
            var pdfContent = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
            pdfContent.style.zoom = "100%";
        };
    }
}


Can you specify a bit how is the architecture of your project ? From where do you call the PopUp ? Which pages are intertwining with each other ? I am just trying to reproduce the error and therefore I need to see how you have configured your component.

@OrisSin The pages are not more intertwined then necessary for Blazor Server oob. I added a full component and the second component would be a exact mirror of the first. It would only call another DB in this simplified version.
